# Matplotlib - Values on top of bar chart is in exponential form

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a bar chart using Matplotlib. I have also added values in top of bar chart using below code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(15,2.5)
ax.barh(y = fig_1['member_casual'], width = fig_1['ride_id'], color = ['orange','lightcoral'], height = 0.8)
ax.set_xlabel("No. of rides")
ax.set_xlim(xmin = 0, xmax = 3500000)
ax.set()
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)

for bars in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bars)
fig.tight_layout()
```

I am getting values on the top bars in exponential form. I want in plain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Iam getting "'this method only works with the ScalarFormatter"' error when I tried it.

Comment: you can specify the axis you want to make the effect on e.g `axis='y'` because its only one axis that has the exponential issue